# Multiple OR rewrite conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know that we can use multiple `RewriteCond` for a `RewriteRule` and I think all conditions should be matched (like AND in programming) to see if rewrite rule works. But I didn't find anything about how to make OR conditions, so if one of those multiple conditions matched, then rewrite rule took place. (*maybe using a flag?!*)

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _“But I didn't find anything”_ – then I guess you haven’t bothered yourself with looking into the docs one bit? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[OR]` is very much supported in `mod_rewrite`. For example consider rule like below which is ignoring rest of the rules if request is for a valid file OR directory OR link.

```
## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# won't affect a valid file/directory/link
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```